# Не получается установить свою музыку для уведомления

Tags: android, аудио

Есть у меня активность почти аналогичная таймеру, по истечении времени появляется уведомление, это все работает, но при попытке установить свою музыку ничего не выходит, может кто знает в чем проблема?
Выдает 2 ошибки
Error:(151, 112) error: illegal character: '\ufeff'
и
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Вот код которым я пытаюсь это сделать
Sound это мелодия в директории raw

notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
final int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("sound.wav", "raw", getPackageName());
```

Для проигрывания аудио:

```
try {
    final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268166/get-file-from-res-raw-folder)